# Show that for all positive x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ the inequality $x+\frac {1} {x}\geq 2$ holds. (Hint?)

Tags: inequality

Show that for all positive x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ the inequality $x+\dfrac {1} {x}\geq 2$ holds. Can you give me a hint?